# filter a pandas df with multiple check of different column equal

Tags: python, pandas

```
,unique_system_identifier,call_sign,date1,date2,date3,date4
0,3929436,WQZL268,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
1,3929436,WQZL268,,,,
2,3929437,WQZL269,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
3,3929437,WQZL269,,,,
4,3929438,WQZL270,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
5,3929438,WQZL270,,,,
6,3929439,WQZL271,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
7,3929439,WQZL271,,,,
8,3929440,WQZL272,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
9,3929440,WQZL272,,,,
10,3929441,WQZL273,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
11,3929441,WQZL273,,,,
12,3929442,WQZL274,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
13,3929442,WQZL274,,,,
14,3929443,WQZL275,14-06-2023,,14-06-2023,
```

I have a df like above need to take only the values which are  date1 & date3 are have different or  date2 or date4 have different if both different also need
how to do with pandas,

the columns are coming as pandas objectnote as datetime/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace missing values first and then compare for not eqaul, chain both mask by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
df1 = df.fillna('')
df = df[df1['date1'].ne(df1['date3']) | df1['date2'].ne(df1['date4'])]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Unnamed: 0, unique_system_identifier, call_sign, date1, date2, date3, date4]
Index: []
```

Comment: Hi bro actually i know this will work. but in my case when fetching it from db its not working after storing same toi the csv its working fine . some filed coming as Nat, some coming as nan..etc

Comment: @abhikrishnan - Answer was edited, can you check?

Comment: in some data the filna('') is not working some are replacing

Comment: @abhikrishnan - sure, I replace NaN to `df1` only for comparing, then filter `df`

Comment: yes bro. thats correct what i said is, in above df1 some values are not replaced as '' when using fillna()

Comment: @abhikrishnan - So need `df.replace('nan', np.nan)` ?

Comment: eg : in date4 when use the fillna('None') then  some fileds are getting None some still empty or nothing dont know and what value coming in that field